# Google Analytics sends only one event per minute

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, event-handling

I'm trying to send different events to GA during user signup process, but it looks sending event is somehow limited to one per minute.

First click on any of the links works fine - I can see XHR request send in browser dev tools and Google Analytics Debugger.
Subsequent clicks do not send event to google, until one minute(roughly) is past -  there is no XHR request, however Debugger logs event send, with only difference - 2 empty parameters: _j1(&jid) and _j2(&gjid)

I've checked [Google Analytics Collection Limits and Quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas), but haven't found similar limits.

Please, find code below.
I've removed everything unnecessary, GA id is for testing purpose, I've tried changing it.

Will appreciate any help or suggestions.
Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
      ga('create', 'UA-38888888-1', 'auto');

      function send_event (name){
        if (ga){
            console.log(name);
            ga("send", "event", "newreg", name );
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body >        
    <a onclick="send_event('aaa')">aaa</a><br><br>
    <a onclick="send_event('bbb')">bbb</a><br><br>
    <a onclick="send_event('ccc')">ccc</a><br><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no such limit, are you inside an app or a website?

Comment: @MichelePisani a website

Comment: Ok, in this case I confirm my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such limit. This code works correctly for me.